# Stopping a loop and returning the value if it doesn't give an error

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, loops

I have this function:

```
def int_input(promt):
    while True:
            try:
                    int(promt)
            except ValueError:
                    print "Not a number, try again."
                    promt = raw_input("Enter your choice:")
```

I want it to break at some point to return **promt** if it is a number, and I can't seem to find a reasonable way.

Comment: `return int(prompt)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not 100% sure what else you're doing, but if you call this, it will not return until you input a valid int.

```
def int_input():
    while True:
        try:
            return int(raw_input("Enter your choice:"))
        except ValueError:
            print "Not a number, try again."

print int_input()
```

output

```
Enter your choice: asdf
Not a number, try again.
Enter your choice: 2df
Not a number, try again.
Enter your choice: 3
3
```

Comment: Function has to be called with promt, but that was easily fixed, thank you, this worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want:

```
def int_input(promt):
    while True:
        try:
            int(promt)
        except ValueError:
            print "Not a number, try again."
            promt = raw_input("Enter your choice:")
            continue

        return int(promt)
```

Comment: It does indeed, thank you.
However, it returns a letter if that's what I enter first

Answer (score 0):

`try`..`except` has an optional `else` clause:

```
def int_input(promt):
    while True:
            try:
                    int(promt)
            except ValueError:
                    print "Not a number, try again."
                    promt = raw_input("Enter your choice:")
            else: # no exception occured, we are safe to leave this loop
               break # or return, or whatever you want to do...
```

but this is not neccessary here, you can simply `return` or `break` inside the `try` (after the int() cast. will only get reached when there wasn't an exception during `int()`).

Answer (score 0):

Ngenator's answer is a bit cleaner, but you could set a variable as a switch to indicate you got a correct value:

```
def int_input(promt):
    got_int = False
    while not got_int:
            try:
                    int(promt)
                    got_int = True
            except ValueError:
                    print "Not a number, try again."
                    promt = raw_input("Enter your choice:")
```